# Display just an image as a "window"?

Tags: macos, graphics

Is there an easy way to display a PNG image (with transparency) as its own “window”, without any OSX window features (title bar, buttons, shadows)?

Ideally, it could also disappear when the mouse is clicked anywhere, or when <kbd>Esc</kbd> is pressed…

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. See Apple's [RoundTransparentWindow](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/RoundTransparentWindow/Introduction/Intro.html) code example:

> This sample demonstrates how to create windows with custom shapes, no title bar, and transparent content. It also shows how to change the shape of the window and recalculate the drop shadow around the window border.

Comment: I was hoping for something simpler ;), like an application. It looks like I'd have to modify the sample quite a bit to accept a file as an argument. If nothing else comes up I'll give it a shot...

Comment: Hopefully someone will come along who knows of an application that does this already. Otherwise, at least you now know it is technically possible.